# How to handle POST requests using Stripe Checkout

Tags: html, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm creating a sign-up service that takes in user contact information in a HTML form. I created a POST endpoint that the form submits to which adds the user into a database. I want to implement Stripe Checkout so that the form submits to the endpoint only after their purchase is completed. Can someone suggest the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use **strip webhooks** feature, in that you can send event to our server your if any event triggered on strip account like payment successful, etc.
[click for stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)

Comment: How do I delay my form from sending a POST until it receives this payment confirmation?

Comment: when you get strip webhook event on your backend sever(like node server), then after modifying or saving stripe incoming data (save to database or any other task) then from there you can easily connect to frontend , using sse event or websockets.